# How to convert HH:MM string to HH:MM:SS hms difftime object in R?

Tags: r, datetime

Trying to convert a time string e.g "0:05" to a hms difftime object e.g 00:05:00 in R.

Reason: trying to combine two dataframes columns, one has a column that is type "hms" "difftime", and other is type "character"

Comment: Do you mean a lubridate `hms` object, or will just `as.difftime("0:05", format="%H:%M")` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to translate a string into a difftime object, you can use `lubridate`. It might be bringing in the big guns for something can easily do with `as.difftme` as @thelatemail suggests, but if you are working with time units, then you want to know about `lubridate` anyway.

You can translate a `"05:00"` HH:MM string into a time object using `lubridate:hm` an translate that into a `difftime` using `as.difftime`:

```
> print(lubridate::as.difftime(lubridate::hm("05:00")))
Time difference of 18000 secs
```

Comment: How do I reverse it? Let's say I have `Time difference of 90 secs` and I would like to get `1:30` as `"hms" "difftime"` class.